# Setting up domain from domain.com with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I have several domains with domain.com , and it used to be if I want to set up a Heroku app with a domain bought at domain.com, all I have to do is point the cname to [name-of-heroku-app].herokuapp.com . And add the domain in Heroku.

But now, if I add a domain at Heroku, the DNS target will be [domain-name].herokudns.com . My older apps on heroku with a custom domain however have a DNS target of [name-of-heroku-app].herokuapp.com .

Am I doing something wrong? Can't seem to get the domain to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Nonetheless. Set the CNAME to `[name-of-heroku-app].herokuapp.com` and not `[domain-name].herokudns.com`.

I would wait a few hours as it depends on many circumstances how fast the change happens.

`[domain-name].herokudns.com` should be used, when you want to add SSL:

> The DNS Target can be different from the Heroku Domain and different for each custom domain. For instance, if you add Heroku SSL on your application, your DNS target will be .herokudns.com, instead of *.herokuapp.com*.
>    [Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)